# Python: function ouputs at the end?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a GUI for collecting oscope data and the acquire button isn't running how I would expect. The `tools.Acquire()` and `tools.MakeData()` are time intensive functions, limited by the speed of the oscope communication, so I would like to print a status telling the user that something is actually happening.

Instead, it seems like the two functions are being carried out and then 'Acquiring....' and 'Acquired' are printed after the fact. Could anyone shed some light on what may be causing the problem?

```
def Acquire_Click(self, event):
    self.statusbox.insert(0.0, 'Acquiring....     ')
    if self.status == 1:
        #Acquire the data
        tools.Acquire()
        tools.MakeData()

        #Make plot
        self.ax.plot(tools.freq, tools.data)
        plt.title('Waveform: ' + tools.plotname)
        plt.ylabel('dB')
        plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')

        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(sticky=Tk.N, pady=20)
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20)

        #Return/update status
        self.statusbox.insert(0.0, 'Acquired          ')
        self.status = 0
        print self.status
    else:
        self.statusbox.insert(0.0, 'Please Reset      ')
    return 1
```

I already tried adding a sleep after the first status update (before the if statement).

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: Guess you are blocking the gui thread

Comment: pretty sure this is TK ... anyway you need to force a screen update after "Aquiring..." or do the work in a thread that will allow the gui to continue running ...

Comment: Yeah, the gui is kind of a mess since it's my first one, but I don't think it's relevant anyway. @Joran Beasley I added a self.update_idletasks() just before the if statement, and it worked like a charm. Thanks! How can I give you credit for the answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Joran Beasley I added a self.update_idletasks() just before the if statement, and it worked like a charm.